# Change default tool window behaviour in IntelliJ IDEA 2016

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

Every time I open a new project in IntelliJ IDEA, the first time I open a particular tool window, for example 'Maven Projects', it appears in 'pinned' mode and remains visible until either I close it, or I go to the view settings for the window (the little cog) and deselect "Pinned Mode". I don't want any of my tool windows to be pinned so this gets a little annoying.

Do you know of a way to change the default behaviour of new project / tool windows?

Comment: I haven't found a dedicated configuration section through the `Settings`, but I solved this by manually un-pinning all of the tool windows (new ones as soon as I use them), then `Window` -> `Store current layout as default`.

Comment: Thanks - that's far better than what I currently have to do. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. There you go, sorry it took so long, I've been busy lately...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as IJ 2016.2 I don't know about a dedicated setting for this. However I used an approach which allows you to define a default layout for all projects. Although the window-pinning works, which is what this question is about, some may not be persisted, such as `Group Modules` setting in the maven tool-window.

Nonetheless, to configure the pinning, you need to do 2 simple things, which you can also see in the GIF below:

1) Manually go and unpin all desired windows

2) Open the `Windows` menu and select `Store current layout as default`

[image: unpin windows & save layout as default]

**P.S.** If you'll be using tool-windows that you've never opened before, or install new plugins which add their own tool-windows, just follow these steps again.

Comment: I just came here to say thank you, you've improved my coding life <3

Comment: @Chris spread the love and knowledge brother, you're most welcome